# What's the solution to this system of equation?

Tags: calculus

$$
xy^3z^3 = yx^3z^3 = zx^3y^3
$$
Is there a way to solve this system?

I think the answer is 1, but i can't verify my intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly if one of the variables is $0$ then all three equations are satisfied. Suppose then that's not the case. We rewrite as
$$y^2 = x^2,\ \ x^2 = z^2,\ \ y^2 = z^2$$
Letting $x$ be a free-variable, we have
$y = \pm x$ and $z=\pm x$.

Comment: So $\left(x,y,z\right) = x\left(1,\pm 1, \pm 1\right)$.

Comment: what is a free variable? isn't the answer 1?

Comment: Free variable means you are free to choose the value as you please. $1$ is not the only possible solution.

Comment: and how do you get to y^2 = x^2 x^2 = z^2 and y^2 = z^2?

Comment: Group the equations in pairs and divide out common variables.

Comment: there are infinite amount of solutions then since x is a free variable? seriously, is this precalc?

Comment: Yes there is an infinite amount of solutions. This seems like a pretty fair pre-calc question in my opinion, there's no need for advanced machinery.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at it, clearly $x=0$, or $y=0$, or $z=0$ is a solution.  So, starting with
\begin{alignat*}{3}
         xy^3z^3 &= yx^3z^3 &&= zx^3y^3
\end{alignat*}
And considering the case where $x \ne 0$, $y \ne 0$, $z \ne 0$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
          y^2z^2 &=  x^2z^2 &&= x^2y^2 
\end{alignat*}
Considering each pair of equalities, we get:
\begin{align*}
          y^2z^2 &= x^2z^2 &      x^2z^2 &= x^2y^2     &     y^2z^2 &= x^2y^2 \\ 
\implies       y &= \pm x  &           z &= \pm x      &          z &= \pm x \\ 
\implies       y &= \pm x  &           z &= \pm x
\end{align*}
Hence the solutions are points of the form
$(0,a,b)$, $(a,0,b)$, $(a,b,0)$, or $(a, \pm a, \pm a)$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.